# Using https with react application

Tags: networking, ssl, javascript, https

Maybe it's an easy question but I couldn't find a satisfied answer.

I have a VPS and react application running on it and i can reach to it via ip like `1.2.3.4:3000`.
Also I have a domain name: `example.com` and I masked ip with this domain name.
I bought a ssl certificate for domain name.

I can reach with http but I want to reach my application via https like `https://www.example.com`, how can I integrate ssl certificate? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Port 3000? Sounds like you’re still using the dev server. Don’t use the dev server.

Comment: You're suggesting to use 443 port?

Comment: No. I’m inferring from your usage of port 3000 that you haven’t properly set up a web server like Apache or nginx. That’s absolutely required for proper hosting. You didn’t say anything about it in your question. // Also, SSL certificates are *free* from Let’s Encrypt.